# Weird Behaviour with respond_to vs plain render with ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form with

```
data-remote="true"
```

Which works.

The controller code was(simplified):

```
render json: { "price" => "£3000" }, status: 200
```

I then changed it to:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render json: { "price" => "£3000" }, status: 200}
  format.html { redirect_to my_url}
end
```

But this dosen't seem to fire the javascript i have hooked into the form like so:

```
form.on("ajax:success", function(event, response) {
  //do stuff
});
```

I checked both the requests in the chrome network tab and they seem to be the same.

So my question(s) are?

What is the difference between the plain render of json and the respond_to with render json?

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Is your js library sending through the correct headers so that your controller knows its an ajax call?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot The js response runs successfully. If thats what you mean.